# Externally add a function to a WordPress Plugin's PHP file (Allowing for easy version update)

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I've got a real brain tickler that I've been wrestling with for a couple of days.

I'm creating a WordPress website for someone (at http://www.lydiala.com/), and using the *Simple WordPress Paypal Shopping Cart Plugin*.

I would like to display the total number of items in the cart, in the top-right corner of my **header.php** file.

I have figured out a function that successfully return this figure, and have added it to the plugin's main PHP file, at `/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-simple-paypal-shopping-cart/wp_shopping_cart.php` (alongside all of the other functions).

I took the following EXISTING function in **wp_shopping_cart.php**:

```
function simple_cart_total() {  
    $grand_total = 0;   
    foreach ((array)$_SESSION['simpleCart'] as $item){      
        $total += $item['price'] * $item['quantity'];       
        $item_total_shipping += $item['shipping'] * $item['quantity'];  
    }   
    $grand_total = $total + $item_total_shipping;
    return number_format($grand_total,2); 
}
```

I then copied it, renamed it and changed it as follows:

```
function total_items() {    
    $grand_total = 0;   
    foreach ((array)$_SESSION['simpleCart'] as $item){      
         $total += $item['quantity'];   
    }
$grand_total = $total;  
    return number_format($grand_total); 
}
```

Now, in my **header.php** I have:

```
echo total_items();
```

Which works brilliantly well!

BUT, when the plugin updates in the future, this newly-added function will be lost when **wp_shopping_cart.php** is overwritten with a new version.

Is there a way to append my custom function to this external `.php` file?  I already tried a few methods, but most of them don't work because they try to load wp_shopping_cart.php, which has *already* been loaded ("Can't redeclare", etc.).

If worse comes to worst, I can always tells the client to call me when updates of this plugin are available.

Comment: Have you tried one of the plugins that allows you to include custom functions? http://justin.ag/technology/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-plugin-custom-functions-php/

Comment: just don't put the function in the plugin-file ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend adding this in a different plugin.

**paypall-totals.php** in your `wp-content/plugins` (don't forget to activate in the wp-admin)

```
/*
plugin-name: paypall totals
description: adds a function to show paypall totals
pluginURI: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17066291/933065
*/

function paypall_total_items() { 
  session_start();   
  $grand_total = 0;   
  foreach ((array)$_SESSION['simpleCart'] as $item){      
    $total += $item['quantity'];   
  }
  $grand_total = $total;  
  return number_format($grand_total); 
}
```

Since it only gets it's data out `$_SESSION` it doesn't matter where you put this function. It also would work in your theme `functions.php`

Also adjust the code in the **header.php**: `echo paypall_total_items();`

Just restore the paypall plugin to it's original code.

Let me know.

Comment: YAY!!! janw FTW!  You're amazing.
That works awesomely.
And, with your help, I just wrote my first WP Plugin!!  That's a great feeling.  Thanks so much, man.

N.B. - At first the plugin wouldn't show up in wp-admin, so I made a couple of additions to the header (like so):

/*
Plugin Name: WP PayPal Item Total
Plugin URI: http://URI_Of_Page_Describing_Plugin_and_Updates
Description: adds a function to show paypall totals
Version: 1.0
Author: Me
Author URI: http://URI_Of_The_Plugin_Author
License: GPL2
*/

Comment: If my answer solved your problem the accept my answer, that's how stackoverflow works. ps more on creating plugins: http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I can not comment now is, should split into a temporary answer.
I think you should not write a plugin, you should put this code in your theme's function.php.
and check if plugin "WordPress Simple Paypal Shopping Cart Plugin." have been installed or not by the following code:

```
if (function_exists ("simple_cart_total")) {...}
```

Comment: uhm, just put this function in your theme, do not need to split into a new plugin, because in fact, only your theme need to use this function :)

Comment: true, but here I advised a plugin to keep the structure clear